# Send Email in Google AppMaker

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-app-maker

A button won't perform following `sendEmail(widget)` on server script when clicked. But it also didn't show any error.

```
function sendEmail(record) {  

  var to = record.OwnerEmail;

  var subject = 'Contract Renewal Notice';

  var body =  'Hello!<br/><p>Please be inform that your following contract is expiring soon:\n<br/>\n</p>'+
          '<b>Contract Name</b>'+'<?= record.Name ?><br/>'+
          '<b>Contract Value</b>'+'<?= record.Currency ?>'+' '+'<?= record.ContractValue ?><br/>'+
          '<b>Contract Owner</b>'+'<?= record.OwnerName ?><br/>'+
          '<b>Vendor Name</b>'+'<?= record.VendorName ?><br/>'+
          '<a href="<?= record.FileURL ?>">Open contract document</a></br>'+
          'Please act upon it. Thank You!';

  MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body);
}
```

Did I do it correctly?

Comment: had import the library and just need to call the MailApp function

Comment: So is it resolved now?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Try adding logger and debugging after every line.

Comment: it shows this error: Wed May 23 12:38:04 GMT+800 2018
Failed due to illegal value in property: a

Comment: On which line? What's the full error

Comment: that is the full error .. I have redefine the question in https://stackoverflow.com/q/50479987/9426876