# Error in sending Email in Google AppMaker

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-app-maker

I want to send an email notification whenever the user clicks on a button. The button will call `sendEmail(widget)` function and invoke a client script as follow:

```
function sendEmail(widget){

  var item = widget.datasource.item;

  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      console.text = error.message;
    })
   .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
      console.text = 'succeed';
   })
 .sendEmails(item);
}
```

then it will pass the datasource on `item` and call `sendEmails(item)` function from a server script as follows:

```
function sendEmails(item){  

  var to = item.OwnerEmail;

  var subject = 'Please Review';

  var body = 'hello<br/>my name is Muhammad Alif bin Azali';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: to,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: body,
      noReply: true
  });
}
```

but when I click the button I got following error instead. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Chances are you are not getting proper value in item object. Try adding `Logger.log(item.OwnerEmail);` after `var to = item.OwnerEmail;`
 line

Comment: D
Wed May 23 14:07:52 GMT+800 2018
muhammadalifazali@airasia.com
E
Wed May 23 14:07:52 GMT+800 2018
Failed due to illegal value in property: a

Comment: item.OwnerEmail hold the correct value

Comment: Could please you remove this one 
 in case it is the same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462355/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass whatever you want as a parameter to your server function. Communication to the server has some [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction-any-server-side-function):

> ...most types are legal, but not Date, Function, or DOM element...
>
> ...objects that create circular references will also fail...

App Maker's records definitely violate those restrictions.

There are different strategies to handle this limitation, one of them is passing record's key as function's parameter.

```javascript
// Client script
function sendEmail(widget) {
  var item = widget.datasource.item;

  google.script.run
  ...
 .sendEmails(item._key);
}

// Server script
function sendEmails(itemKey) {
  var item = app.models.MyModel.getRecord(itemKey);
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Pavel now I understand why and it work just fine thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Mail Body needs to be converted in HTML Body,

Here's the sample

```
function sendEmails(item){  

  var to = item.OwnerEmail;

  var subject = 'Please Review';

  var body = 'hello<br/>my name is Muhammad Alif bin Azali'; 
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(body);
  var htmlBody = template.evaluate().getContent();


  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: to,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: htmlBody ,
      noReply: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Mail sending code is perfect. Seems some other issue. Have you received emails from Appmaker before?

Comment: yes I have. Did the "item" variable pass the correct value? I am not so sure about it